# How do I make a background image fade with scrolling in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, scrolltop

I want to make a fading background image when I scroll my page down.

I had seen something with two divs that fade with opacity. Something like this:

```
<div class="background1"></div>
<div class="background2"></div>
```

And than some kind of jQuery code, but I didn't really get it.

Hope somebody can help.

I guess it would be possible to do with scrollTop, but I am not sure how to get that.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Zva5N/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. Bind an event to the document to check for scrolling and see what the height is.

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $("html").scrollTop();
    if(scrollTop > 150){
        $(".background2").fadeIn();
    }
    else
        $(".background2").fadeOut();
})
```

Comment: but what does the line (scrollTop > 150) actually mean, I don't get any wiser by just copying ;)

Comment: Good catch and sorry I missed your point. As [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) puts it, "[scrollTop] get(s) the current vertical position of the scroll bar for the first element...". Essentially, take the item that has been scrolled and scrollTop will return how many pixels are between where the user has scrolled to and the top of that selected element. (scrollTop > 150) means that the user has scrolled more than 150 pixels down the element (in this case the document). I hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I found another way but this works as well.